# Do not see camera in AVD

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am a beginner in mobile app development. I am setting up my dev IDE and AVD. I have created a new AVD with the following specs:

> 1. Target: Android 7
> 2. Platform 7.0
> 3. API Level: 24
> 4. CPU: Intel Atom x86
> 5. Device Nexus 6
> 6. Skin: Skin with dynamic hardware controls
> 7. Front Camera: Emulated
> 8. Back Camera: Webcam0
> 9. Memory Ram: 512, VM Heap: 32
> 10. Internal Storage: 200 MiB
> 11. Use Host GPU

I am using Intel HAXM and have disabled Hyper-V. My issue is that I do not see camera in the AVD. I have to develop an app that uses camera. Please help

Comment: Follow this article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studios-emulator-for-android/   it will help

Comment: When you start the emulator, it didn't has a camera ?

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT No. It doesn't